# one lemma for proving Butterfly lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

> $(C\cap H).(C\cap K)=(C\cap HK)$

Actually I was trying to prove Butterfly lemma I got stuck on this lemma. If this lemma can be proved then I am done. But I can not prove or disprove it. Can anyone please help me out? C, H, K are subgroups of G.

Comment: $A . B$ is the group generated by $\{a\cdot b\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$?

Comment: Can you say what $C$, $H$, $K$ are, and possibly add the tag 'group-theory'?

Comment: Please give more background on the proof, state what $C$, $H$ and $K$ are and where you precisely got stuck. What is the source you are studying?

Comment: My question might have been changed by admin I think. I gave a photo of this equation and I had elaborated my question. sorry. Please see the edited one.